# React Native List Updating Wrong State Before Going to Child Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to perform add function on my list. The way it works is that I have a parent screen showing the whole list of items with a button at the top (navigation bar) to add a new item. The problem is that if I add a new item (and it adds correctly to the list of items), the navigation function does not receive the right state of items when going to child screen again, causing a mismatch number of items upon the new task creation.

```
Parent.js 
    const handleOpenNewTask = () => {
        //items before going to child screen (onTaskCreated is a callback from child to update list)
        
        //this is where the wrong number of items shows, taskList is not updated here!
        console.log(taskList)
        
        navigation.navigate(routes.NEW_TASK, {
            onTaskCreated
        });
    };

    //callback when child screen is finished
    const onTaskCreated = ({ newTask, id }) => {

        // Create a new array based on current state:
        let list = [...taskList];

        // Add item to it
        list.push({value: id});

        //updates correctly first time
        setTaskList(list);
    };

    //update header with button to add new item
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <NewTaskHeaderRight onClick={() => handleOpenNewTask()} />
            ),
        });
    }, [navigation]);
```

Basically, if I have an empty list and go to child screen it would add it to the list and show on the screen. However, when I go to child screen again, the `taskList` in `handleOpenNewTask` is not updated and I assume I am doing it wrong because navigation doesn't catch the `taskList` state? What should I do?

Comment: is it correct that I should add ```taskList``` to ```useLayoutEffect``` state update conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below, Pass the taskList as a dependency to the hook, which will cause the navigation to update with new state.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <NewTaskHeaderRight onClick={() => handleOpenNewTask()} />
            ),
        });
    }, [navigation,taskList]);
```